# Does Immerwolf's bonus stay after it leaves the battlefield?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

A little while ago I was playing two of my friends. One of my friends was playing a wolf/werewolf deck with [Immerwolf](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Immerwolf) and a few other creatures out on the battlefield.  I was playing an enchantment deck and cast [Path To Exile](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Path%20To%20Exile) on the Immerwolf. Once the spell resolved my friend didn't remove the +1/+1 from his other creatures (from Immerwolf's ability).

I reasoned that since they weren't actual +1/+1 counters, they would no longer affect his creatures, since Immerwolf was in exile.  He disagreed, saying that the +1/+1 would stay, whether or not Immerwolf was in play.

I didn't really feel like pushing the issue since it was just a kitchen table game and it also didn't really affect the outcome of the game.  I'm just curious as to who was correct.

Comment: This is a fairly common newbie question that's shown up on this site before in various guises (don't feel bad if failed to find it in a search, it's hard without already knowing the proper terminology). This answer should have you covered: http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/18216/1910

Answer (score 6):

**Immerwolf's ability only gives other creatures +1/+1 while Immerwolf is on the battlefield.**

Immerwolf's ability is a [static ability](http://mtgsalvation.gamepedia.com/Static_ability) that creates a [continuous effect](http://mtgsalvation.gamepedia.com/Continuous_effects). The specific rules that covers this scenario are:

> - **611.3.** A continuous effect may be generated by the static ability of an object.
>
>   - **611.3a** A continuous effect generated by a static ability isn’t “locked in”; it applies at any given moment to whatever its text indicates.
>   - **611.3b** The effect applies **at all times that the permanent generating it is on the battlefield** or the object generating it is in the appropriate zone.

As soon as Immerwolf leaves the battlefield, the ability stops existing. Since it isn't "locked in" to those specific creatures that it was affecting, those creatures lose the power and toughness bonus.