# Are counters the same as a creature's power/toughness?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I put 4 +1/+1 counters on a 1/1 creature, so now it is a 5/5. My opponent casts a spell that says to remove all +1/+1 counters from target creature. Is my creature now a 1/1? Or are all creatures 0/0 with +1 counters on them?  If they are 0/0s, then since all counters would be removed, is my card dead?

Related, can I use [Sage of Hours](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSage%20of%20Hours%5d), again and again, or would it be dead after the first time I use it due to removing all counters?

Comment: When asking a question about terminology, I would *always* name all of the cards involved. When you don't know the terminology, it can be a little more difficult to understand exactly what you are asking. Once we see the cards involved, the question usually becomes apparent.

Comment: I have edited your post for clarity. I don't understand why you mention Oreskos or Ephrara; they don't have anything to do with +1/+1 counters.

Comment: @Rainbolt  im sorry i confused myself,

Comment: @Keshav Please do not edit out your primary question, particularly after it has been answered

Comment: sort of related: http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/18214/are-1-1-counters-different-from-1-1-effects

Answer (score 6):

Counters are a specific object in the game, usually represented by a physical token (glass beads, tiny dice, pennies if you're desperate, &c.) so you can keep track of them.

+1/+1 counters are a specific kind of counter with a baked-in ability: modifying the power and toughness of a creature they are attached to.

**Only things specified as "counters" in the game rules or card text are counters.**

All of these things are **not** counters and do not involve counters:

- Your creature's base power and toughness, and effects that set them to specific values.
- A creature's power and toughness that gets set by the card text while the value in the corner just says "*/*."
- A card that modifies a creature's power and toughness, such as "target creature gets +3/+3 until end of turn" or "all white creatures get +1/+1."

---

The only times you're likely to be interacting with counters in Magic without a card being super explicit are planeswalker loyalty and a handful of specialized set mechanics:

- Infect and Wither turn damage into -1/-1 counters.
- Suspend and cumulative upkeep both use counters to keep track of their "ticks."