# MTG Necromancer's Magemark

Tags: magic-the-gathering

[Necromancer's Magemark](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bNecromancer%27s%5d%2b%5bMagemark%5d) says

```
Enchant Creature
Creatures you control that are enchanted get +1/+1
If a creature you control that's enchanted would die, 
return it to it's owners hand instead.
```

Is that a +1/+1 **counter**? Or is it just a modification to the P/T?

Also, given the language it reads as if it means to say **any** creature enchanted by **any** enchantment. Correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the card text does not use the word "counter" it is not a counter. It's just a modification to P/T.  See also: [Are +1/+1 counters different from +1/+1 effects?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/18214/are-1-1-counters-different-from-1-1-effects)

And the return clause says "a creature" which means any creature (you control), so yes, any enchanted creature you control returns to hand instead of dying.